Customised UITableViewHeaderFooterView registering causes crash
Created a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView:
class TableSectionHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
let title = UILabel()

override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    configureContents()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func configureContents() {
    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    contentView.addSubview(title)


        // Center the label vertically, and use it to fill the remaining
        // space in the header view.
        title.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor/*image.trailingAnchor,
               constant: 8*/),
        title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
               contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        title.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor)
    ])
}

}
declaration of UIViewController
class PopupTimetableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView?

in viewDidLoad register:
self.tableView?.register(TableSectionHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader”)

delegate:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // Dequeue with the reuse identifier
    if let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "sectionHeader") as? TableSectionHeader {
        view.title.text = self.groupDates?[section].month ?? "Unknown"
        //           view.image.image = UIImage(named: sectionImages[section])
        return view
    }
    return nil
}

on registering the app crashes:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSLayoutConstraint registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000201cc80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010559810c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001035eeda8 objc_exception_throw + 72
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055adbf4 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010559c40c forwarding + 1268
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010559eb2c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   iGCSE_Entries.debug.dylib           0x0000000103df2ba4 $s13iGCSE_Entries28PopupTimetableViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyF + 272
6   iGCSE_Entries.debug.dylib           0x0000000103df2cd4 $s13iGCSE_Entries28PopupTimetableViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 36
7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001418981a0 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 80
8   UIKitCore                           0x000000014189cd58 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 908
using iOS 18.2 in xcode 16.2
Is UITableViewHeaderFooterView broken?

The crash says that self.tableView is an instance of NSLayoutConstraint - Check the assignment in interface builder. It looks like you might have dragged a constraint to your outlet, not the tableview

This part of the exception:

[NSLayoutConstraint registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000201cc80

says that the method registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: was called on an instance of NSLayoutConstraint and that that class does not implement that method.
You should be calling that method on an instance of UITableView.  The most likely cause is that you have made an error in Interface Builder and assigned a reference to a constraint to your tableView IBOutlet; Remove the assignment in Interface Builder and re-establish it to the table view.

I wouldn’t have spotted that, as can’t recall making a reference to a constraint to your tableView, must have inadvertently.
